# Tailwind center one item in row

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a row of items

[image]

I want to make it so the selected item is in the center of the div, and the others position either side so they are in same order.

Here is my code:

```
<div className="flex mx-auto justify-center items-center">
  <Circle selected={selected === ActionOptions.NONE} onClick={e => setSelected(ActionOptions.NONE)} title="None" />
  <Circle selected={selected === ActionOptions.ICON} onClick={e => setSelected(ActionOptions.ICON)} title="Icon">
    {Icon(Icons.CHECK, selected === ActionOptions.ICON ? 'w-20 h-20' : 'w-8 h-8')}
  </Circle>
  <Circle selected={selected === ActionOptions.EMOJI} onClick={e => setSelected(ActionOptions.EMOJI)} title="Emoji">
    {Icon(Icons.SMILE, selected === ActionOptions.EMOJI ? 'w-20 h-20' : 'w-8 h-8')}
  </Circle>
  <Circle selected={selected === ActionOptions.TIMER} onClick={e => setSelected(ActionOptions.TIMER)} title="Timer">
    <ClockIcon className={selected === ActionOptions.TIMER ? 'w-20 h-20' : 'w-8 h-8'} />
  </Circle>
</div>

function Circle({
  selected,
  children,
  onClick,
  title,
}: PropsWithChildren<{ selected: boolean; onClick: (e) => void; title: string }>) {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
      <div
        onClick={onClick}
        className={`rounded-full flex justify-center items-center ${
          selected ? 'w-32 h-32 border-4' : 'w-14 h-14 border-2'
        } mx-2  border-white bg-white/10`}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
      <span className="text-xs">{title}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any clues on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I understood correctly what you want, but you can try to change flex-order like that:

```
const Circles = [
  { title: 'None', option: ActionOptions.NONE, order: 1 },
  { title: 'Icon', option: ActionOptions.ICON, order: 1 },
  { title: 'Emoji', option: ActionOptions.EMOJI, order: 3 },
  { title: 'Timer', option: ActionOptions.TIMER, order: 3 },
]

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<ActionOptions>();

  return (
    <div className="flex mx-auto justify-center items-center transition-all duration-1000">
      {Circles.map(({ title, option, order }) => {
        return (
          <Circle
            key={title}
            selected={selected === option}
            onClick={() => setSelected(option)}
            title={title}
            order={order}
          >
            <div>{option}</div>
          </Circle>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export function Circle({ selected, children, onClick, title, order }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`item flex flex-col items-center justify-center cursor-pointer ${
        selected ? `order-2` : `order-${order}`
      }`}
    >
      <div
        onClick={onClick}
        className={`rounded-full flex justify-center items-center ${
          selected ? 'w-32 h-32 border-4' : 'w-14 h-14 border-2'
        } mx-2  border-white bg-white/10`}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
      <span className="text-xs">{title}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```